# How to move a field to a different region using Omega sub-theme / D7?

Tags: theming

I used to be pretty good at theming Drupal sites, but I haven't done it much since D7. I added a custom field to my Basic content type and I want to put it in a Sidebar if it exists. What's the best way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you IRC! At least two modules will help with this (quotes included are from their project pages):

- [CCK Blocks](https://www.drupal.org/project/cck_blocks):

  > Since version 6.x-1.1 , the module does not hide the field in the node's content area anymore. You can do that for yourself in the display settings for your content type.
  >
  > CCK blocks will define a display mode named "CCK Blocks", which you can use to configure the display of fields when they are appearing as blocks.
  >
  > This allows you show the field both in the node's content area and in the CCK block, with different display settings.
- [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds):

  > ... allows you to take full control over how your content is displayed using a drag and drop interface. Arrange your nodes, views, comments, user data etc. the way you want without having to work your way through dozens of template files. A predefined list of layouts (D7 only) is available for even more drag and drop fun!
  >
  > By defining custom view modes (build modes in D6), you can define how one piece of content should be displayed in different places such as teaser lists, search results, the full node, views etc.